# Await inside a for loop inside an async function gives strange result

Tags: javascript, for-loop, async-await

Can someone help explain to me why is it behave this way?

To the best of my knowledge, adding the `await sleep(1)` line should not affect the code flow in this case. However, it does.

```js
function sleep(time) {
  return new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, time));
}

async function test(target) {
    const ids = { a: ['a1', 'a2'], b: ['b3', 'b4'] }[target];
    for (id of ids) {
        console.log('X.', target, id);
        // await sleep(1);
        console.log('Y.', target, id);
    }
}

test('a');
test('b');
```

[image: before]

[image: after]

Why?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please include both examples as [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) this makes it easier to debug. See [Why you shouldn't upload images of code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) for more info

Comment: Because you should `await test('a'); await test('b');`. You arre currently running two asynchronous operations concurrently. Besides, `id` is a global variable, so both operations reuse and overwrite the same variable at the same time. No wonder you're getting a chaotic output :)

Comment: `for(id of` makes `id` global, make it local to your for loop using `for(const id of`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `for (const id of ids) {`. Without `const` or `let`, you're defining `id` on the global scope.

```
function sleep(time) {
  return new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, time));
}

async function test(target) {
    const ids = { a: ['a1', 'a2'], b: ['b3', 'b4'] }[target];
    for (const id of ids) {
        console.log('X.', target, id);
        await sleep(1);
        console.log('Y.', target, id);
    }
}

test('a');
test('b');
```

Comment: This is great point. If it is still happening, then this can be the answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392111/console-log-async-or-sync
It should never happen if console.log is sync, but that is not standardized. Seems like you've proven that console.log should be considered async.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the problem!

Answer (score 2):

You're not waiting `test('a')` to finish.

When `test('b')` is reached, `test('a')` is still running (because it's an async function). If you want it to finish before starting the other one use `.then()`:

```
test('a').then(()=>test('b'));
```